# Unable to view output of PHP files on localhost:8080

Tags: php, localhost

I am building my files in Notepad++ and running them through Apache & MySQL via XAMPP on port 8080 and 3306 respectively. I am fully able to logon to localhost:8080 and PHPmyAdmin but I cannot logon to any of the files themselves like "localhost:logon/index.php" when I attempt that it sends me to a google search page or is unable to connect to the server at all depending on the file. I tried several things to give me access and they either removed all access to localhost or had no effects at all. I guess getting the google search page is progress. I really need to be able to see the actual results of these pages. I've scanned all of the posts for PHP here with no luck and googled several other options prior to posting. Here's the code for the small file mentioned above:

```
    <?php 

session_start();
    $_SESSION;

    $user_data = check_login($con); 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html 
<html>
<head>
    <title>Java Hobbit</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
    <h1>This is the index page</h1>
    <br>
    Hello, Username.
    <style>
        #text{
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 16px;
            color: #660066;
            width: 100%
        }
        
        #button{
            padding: 10px;
            width: 100px;
            color: #660066;
            background-color: #c4d3ca;
            border: none;
        }

        #box{
            background-color: #d2b4da;
            margin: auto;
            width: 300px;
            padding: 20px;
        }
    </style>

    <div id="box">
    
        <form method="post">
            <div style="font-size: 20px; margin: 10px;">Login</div>
            <input id="text" type="text" name="user_name"><br><br>
            <input id="text" type="password" name="password"><br><br>
            
            <input id="button" type="submit" value="Login"><br><br>
            
            <a href="signup.php">Click to Signup</a><br><br>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried
http://localhost/logon/index.php

That's a more accurate way of accessing your file in the "logon" directory.

Comment: Yes, I get "This site can’t be reachedlocalhost refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Which is why I tried turning off the firewall. And I've tried adding permissions for all the programs I can to allow them through the firewall, with no luck there either.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).